# Display all file with prefix id

Tags: php

I have user folder /folder_name and there are files with name prefix
Example this pattern `id_radom.example`

```
5__1490952185fed525d92.24525311.jpg
15__4658521860030a66d0.90328377.jpg
15__6654521861778060e1.31100475.jpg
15__6654521861778060e1.31100475.jpg
```

I want to display all of these image(`id=15`) using php

I am trying:

```
$path = "uploads/registered_files/".$_SESSION['user_data']['username'];
$a = glob("/".$path."/".$article->article_id."__",GLOB_BRACE);
print_r($a);
```

But I got empty `array()`

Comment: Use the `glob()` function.

Comment: `glob()` is too memory expensive solution for directories with a lot of files.http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.glob.php#102931

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution may look like this:

```
if (false === ($handle = opendir($path))) {
    //catch error here
}

$images = array();
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    preg_match('/^15__.*/', $file)) and $images[] = $file;
}
closedir($handle);

foreach ($images as $image) {
    echo '<img src="',$path,DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$image,'"/>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`/".$path."/".$article->article_id."__"` is pointing to the root of the filesystem, not to the root of your website. This might be the problem.

Try removing the first / or prefix it with the absolute path to your website's root.